# How to enable VDPAU on GStreamer?

Tags: nvidia, gstreamer, vdpau

I'm currently experiencing a bit of lag on 720 HD videos. I am hoping VDPAU will help. How do I enable it on either GStreamer-based video players?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

VDPAU is enable by default on the official nVidia binaries. If your [card supports VDPAU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VDPAU#Device_drivers_and_hardware_supporting_VDPAU) you just need to install them and use a [player that supports VDPAU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VDPAU#Software_supporting_VDPAU).

Other then that video hardware acceleration should be implemented via `libva` if the `vdpau-va-driver` is installed.

```
sudo apt-get install libva1 vdpau-va-driver vainfo
```

Gstreamer should take care of the rest or if you are going to use a player like `vlc` you should have an option that enables that in the player it self.

To see if your card is supported run the command `vainfo`.

If you get an output like this

```
libva: libva version 0.32.0
libva: va_getDriverName() returns 0
libva: Trying to open /usr/lib/dri/vboxvideo_drv_video.so
libva: va_openDriver() returns -1
vaInitialize failed with error code -1 (unknown libva error),exit
```

you card has no hardware acceleration.

If on the other hand you get something like this

```
libva: libva version 0.32.0
     Xlib:  extension "XFree86-DRI" missing on display ":0.0".
     libva: va_getDriverName() returns 0
     libva: Trying to open /usr/lib/dri/fglrx_drv_video.so
     libva: va_openDriver() returns 0
     vainfo: VA API version: 0.32
     vainfo: Driver version: Splitted-Desktop Systems XvBA backend for VA-API - 0.7.8
     vainfo: Supported profile and entrypoints
     VAProfileH264High               :  VAEntrypointVLD
     VAProfileVC1Advanced            :  VAEntrypointVLD
```

your hardware supports video acceleration and its enabled.

Comment: This unfortunately doesn't seem to be totally true anymore. `nvidia-smi` shows that I have the proprietary drivers installed for the 1080 Ti (which does support VDPAU), but vainfo returns -1. Not sure if this is because I'm operating remotely.