# Clarifications about Gstreamer

Tags: gstreamer

I'm a bit confused about what Gstreamer does.

- Does it come installed by default with Ubuntu ?

  - If so which version  is the default for 14.04?
- Does it provide hardware accelerated video playback (decoding) ?

  - If so does it work with VA-API and VDPAU or is it an alternative to those?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gstreamer 1.0 is installed by default on 14.04 (See the desktop image [manifest](http://releases.ubuntu.com/14.04/ubuntu-14.04-desktop-amd64.manifest))

But you need to install additional plugins to get VA-API support.

Install the following [package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/gstreamer1.0-vaapi) in a Terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install gstreamer1.0-vaapi
```

For VDPAU, check this answer: [How to enable VDPAU on GStreamer?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/78936/how-to-enable-vdpau-on-gstreamer)

Comment: Thanks for clearing up a few things
- is Gstreamer a framework on which media playing software is built? 
    - If so which softwares use it? 
    - Is it capable of hw accelerated decoding without VDPAU or VA API?

Comment: Gstreamer is used by Totem (the default) media player, clementine and many more. Gstreamer won't use GPU acceleration without those additional plugins (Visit this [page](http://docs.gstreamer.com/display/GstSDK/Playback+tutorial+8%3A+Hardware-accelerated+video+decoding) for further details)